# iTunes is threatening to overwrite my apps following a hard drive crash induced reinstallation

Tags: itunes, iphone

I had a hard drive crash and now that I reinstalled iTunes it seems to threaten to replace my current iPhone apps with the redownloaded apps on my new hard drive. This will cause me to lose all my progress in the various games that I have. Is there a way to turn the app sync on without having it rewrite my current apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the computer is authorised on the same account as the iPhone, then delete the apps from your hard drive.  The next time you sync your iPhone, the apps will be copied over from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you only want to manually transfer apps from your iPhone to your iTunes, with your device connected, right-click on the iPhone icon on the left-hand side pane in iTunes and select "Transfer purchases".